# HTML animation creation

Tags: html, animation, css-animations

I want to make an ultra simple animation on a web page using a sequence of five images: *Image1*, *Image2*, *Image3*, *Image4* and *Image5*.

I plan to start by experimenting, displaying each image for about 0.1 second and then see.

I have never done that before. What is the simplest way for me to get started?

I have searched the net for some tutorial and I have found a few documents about *HTML/CSS* animation, but it does not seem very clear and looks far more complicated than I need for my use case.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: with javascript?

Comment: Yes with javascript. After digging a bit more I found this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-frame-by-frame-animation-using-css-and-javascript which got me started. And I was able to make a little animation.I wanted to use SVG images, but it was easy to change.

Comment: ok great, I checked your link, seems you have everything you need, happy coding